# link onClick to another files onClick react

Tags: reactjs

openResume hook in File1.js does an Animation onClick
and i want to link this same animation on File2.js
onclick. How do i achieve it?

File1.js

```
const ExpandDiv=()=>{ 
   const [initStyle, open] = openResume("ResumeContentStyling") 

     return(
        <div onClick={open} className={initStyle}>Content Goes here</div>
      )
      }
```

File2.js

```
const Profile=()=>{

return(

<div onClick={??} className="ProfileStyle"> Content.... </div>

) }
```

Comment: You can export from one file and import from another. If this component is nested, you can use prop but i guess not nested.

Comment: You question is unclear to me, if u could explain a little bit more. there can be multiple solution what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: So basically, in File1.js the onClick does an animation using the hook i created and is applied to the className initStyle. I want the exact same animation driven via onClick which is located in another file(File2.js). Hope i am clear? I tried a importing and using props but didnt seem to work

Comment: You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass data between component nested in same parent

Comment: Sweet, thank you. let me give it a go.